# Rollback old value of datagridview when editing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `datagridview1`. When user edit the cell value, I want to check the validation of data. If not valid then rollback the cell value to old value.

In the `CellValidating` event, I used:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

but the value not rolled back
How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting `e.Cancel = true` simply cancels the edit from exiting, forcing the user to edit the current cell until it is valid.  Instead, allow the edit to occur, but reset the value to the original.  Replace the line of code you've posted with the following:

```
dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

---

Edit: Or just replace the above with the following line of code. This has further advantage of not losing the data type and cancels the addition of the `NewRow` if one was added.

```
this.dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
```

Comment: +1, thx. Only disadvantage of using CancelEdit() is that the cell remains selected in edit mode. I prefer to use the restore (your first answer) and proceed with a **dataGridView.EndEdit()**. In that case, the grid cell marker is restored, not the edit mode cursor.